# Cannot display settings field

Tags: plugins, settings-api

A plugin with a settings page does not render its settings field `rma_base_url`. No errors are thrown. Page is created in Settings, heading and submit button are rendered.

Code:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'remote_member_auth_menu');

function remote_member_auth_menu() {
    add_options_page('Remote Member Auth Options', 'Remote Member Auth', 'manage_options', 'rma', 'remote_member_auth_options');
}

function remote_member_auth_options() {
    if (!current_user_can('manage_options')) {
        wp_die(__('You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.'));
    }
    echo '<div class="wrap">' .
        '<h3>Remote Member Authentication Settings</h3>' .
        '<form method="post" action="options.php">';
    settings_fields('rma_options');
    do_settings_sections('rma');
    submit_button('Set base url');
    echo '</form>' .
        '</div>';
}

function register_rma_settings() {
    register_setting('rma_options', 'rma_base_url');
    add_settings_field('rma_base_url', 'Base URL', 'rma_base_url_string', 'rma');
}

add_action('admin_init', 'register_rma_settings');

function rma_base_url_string() {
    $options = get_option('rma_options');
    echo "<input id='rma_base_url' name='rma_options[rma_base_url]' size='40' type='text' value='{$options['rma_base_url']}' />";
}
```

#### Edit:

Modifying form code with `echo do_settings_sections('rma') ? 'something' : 'nothing';` renders `nothing`, so `do_settings_sections('rma')` is empty. `echo strlen(do_settings_sections('rma'))` renders `0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Modifying form code with echo do_settings_sections('rma') ?
>   'something' : 'nothing'; renders nothing, so
>   do_settings_sections('rma') is empty.

With that in mind, I dont see you adding a section in your posted code.
If you add a section to your `register_rma_settings()` function, and than add this section to your `add_settings_field()`, than the input will show.

```
function register_rma_settings() {

    // add_settings_section( $id, $title, $callback, $page );
    // you can use $callback to add some descriptive text otherwise leave it blank, ''
    add_settings_section( 'rma_section', 'some title', 'section_description', 'rma' );

    register_setting('rma_options', 'rma_base_url');

    // we also added our new section id "rma_section" at last argument to the following function
    add_settings_field('rma_base_url', 'Base URL', 'rma_base_url_string', 'rma', 'rma_section');
}
```

### Do you not want to use any section or why you have not created one?

**Update**
@geoB yeah first I had also the impression that you dont necessarily need to define a section in the `add_settings_field()` function.
When we read the codex about that function, we see the `section` argument as `optional`, like `$section (string) (optional)`
**BUT** we can also see that if we did not add a `section`, the argument will use `default`.

I also tried inserting specifically `'default'` as a section argument, but the setting will not show up. (even not on other settings pages)
I than tried inserting `''` as a section argument, but also, nothing is shown.

So it *seems* that `section` is not really optional.

Comment: ["Settings Sections are the groups of settings you see on WordPress settings pages with a shared heading."](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_settings_section)  I'm under the impression that having its own page (`rma`) for the setting avoided the necessity of a section. Sections seem relevant only when adding settings to an existing page such as General or Discussion.

Comment: Just accepted your answer.  I'm surprised that adding a section is necessary, but Oh Well!  Thanks. Now to figure out why the value is not saved even after using `submit_button()`

Comment: @geoB I updated my answer with some test details regarding `add_settings_field()` and the section argument.